# Install .exe silently using cmd

Tags: python, windows-installer, silent-installer

I want to install these two Python packages `pyHook-1.5.1.win32-py2.7` and `pywin32-218.win32-py2.7` from cmd without any user interaction.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I already solved this, I hope it can help anyone who come here looking for answers. I converted the .exe files to .msi using a program called exe to msi converter then I called it from cmd using this command msiexec /i pyHook-1.5.1.win32-py2.7.msi /qn

Answer (score 0):

For python 3.4 or 2.7 and above, you could use the bundled [easy_install](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html) binary.

```
Scripts/easy_install.exe pywin32-221.win32-py2.7.exe
```